# Where can I find Word 2010 fonts?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-word-2010

I have Word 2010 with an option for the font *bubble1*. My printing company needs this font to print something, but it is not available on their systems, so I'm trying to find a way to download this font for use in other programs.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of what that font looks like.

Answer (score 4):

The fonts that come with Microsoft Office 2010 are installed into the default font folder in Windows.

As such, they should be available in any other Windows application that makes use of the Windows font repository.

By default this location should be

```
%WINDIR%\Fonts
```

But I seriously doubt the font has any relation to Word 2010 at all. You're just seeing it in Word because Word uses the Windows font repository. You most likely already obtained that font from an external resource.

---

When typing `bubble1 font` into Google, I get this as the first result over at [dafont.com](http://www.dafont.com/bubble1.font):
[image]

Is that the font you're looking for by any chance?

Comment: Thanks for the response Oliver, I have had a look at this link to install new fonts, but this assumes you have access to the bubble 1 font which my printer dosent, do you know how he accesses it?

Comment: @Emily: Well, you can download the font over on [dafont.com](http://www.dafont.com/bubble1.font). **If** that is, in fact, the font you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [list of the fonts](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2121313) that come with Office 2010. If you need them professionally, they can be [purchased separately](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/product.aspx?PID=163).

Either way, it does not look like there is a font called [*bubble1*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&sa=X&q=bubble%201%20font), so it is likely a [third-party font](http://www.dafont.com/bubble1.font) that you installed. Depending on the license for the font, you may be able to simply copy it from your fonts directory (`%windir%\fonts`).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this problem is to embed the fonts you have used in the document when you save it. You can do this by going to `File > Options > Save` and checking the boxes under `Preserve fidelity when sharing this document:`

```
 ☑ Embed fonts in the file  
  ☑ Embed only characters used in the document  
  ☑ Do not embed common system fonts
```